# Any one help me to find out the unexpected token issue?

Tags: protractor

**Unexpected token issue is shown on command prompt**

```
onPrepare: function() {
    return browser.getCapabilities().then(caps) {
        var sessionId = caps.caps_['webdriver.remote.sessionid'];
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: 'C:/report/report/screenshots' + sessionId
        }));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to pass a `callback function` for `then()` function.

```
return browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
    var sessionId = caps.caps_['webdriver.remote.sessionid'];
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        savePath: 'C:/report/report/screenshots' + sessionId
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) one more issue related to above code. I am getting this error " cannot read property 'webdriver.remote.sessionid' of undefined'

Comment: change `var sessionId = caps.caps_['webdriver.remote.sessionid'];` to `var sessionId = caps.get('webdriver.remote.sessionid');`